# Debian 7 locales not found

Tags: debian, docker, locale

I need to install en_US and it_IT locales. I work with Docker containers but I think is indipendent between Debian and container based on Debian.

I execute these commands:

```
root@debian:/# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=

root@debian:/# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

I tried this command:

```
root@debian:/# dpkg-reconfigure locales
dpkg-query: package 'locales' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales is not installed.
```

Comment: Note that debian 7 is *old* oldstable. You may want to update. Soon.

Comment: consider dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You’re on the right track, however you need to install the `locales` package before you can configure it:

```
apt-get install locales
```

If you want to have all locales without needing any configuration, use `locales-all` instead:

```
apt-get install locales-all
```

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, as you were trying to do.

Comment: How can I take all locales without interact with shell? I need to make a Dockerfile.